# R - igraph: convert a .csv file into a graph file

Tags: r, csv, igraph

I have a .csv file with this structure:

```
a,b,c,d

a,c

c,b,a
```

where each line corresponds to a complete undirected graph.

That means: for the line 1, I would need an igraph result like:

```
a-b

a-c

a-d

b-c

b-d

c-d
```

Would you know an easy way to convert my .csv file to a such graph in R?

Comment: You should convert your csv file to one of the formats that igraph can read listed in http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Foreign.html

Comment: Thanks, what I'd like to do is more the pre-processing of the .csv file to have the edgelist.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear if you want a single graph or a list of graphs (1 for each line).

Assuming the latter:

```
v <- readLines(textConnection("a,b,c,d
a,c
c,b,a"))

library(igraph)
f <- function(x) graph.data.frame(t(combn(strsplit(x,",")[[1]],2)),directed=FALSE)
g <-lapply(v,f)
par(mfrow=c(1,length(g)))
lapply(g,plot)
```

[image]

Assuming the former (not much point in this).

```
g.full <- do.call(graph.union,g)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(g.full)
```

[image]