# R: How to convert CSV data to igraph object

Tags: r, csv, igraph, read.csv

I'm going to analyse (some exploratory analysis and I'm new to this subject) large networks in R. So I have a FLICKR data set in hand.

[FLICKR DATA](http://datasets.syr.edu/datasets/Flickr.html)

If you see the data set, it consists of 4 different CSV file with different attribute of a graph or network. How to convert this data to `igraph` object?

I have see the following solution in the Stack overflow.

[SOL 1,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788493/reading-csv-data-with-igraph)
[SOL 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610013/r-igraph-convert-a-csv-file-into-a-graph-file)

I also know there is a function called `csv.to.igraph` function in the `influenceR` package, but unable to serve my purpose.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your quenstion is (probably) too broad. It should focus on a single problem.

But here is a first approach, it reads the relevant csv (with edges), and creates a (directed) graph

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)
edges <- data.table::fread("./data/Flickr-dataset/data/edges.csv")
g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, directed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. One question, why there are four different .csv file in the data set?

Comment: don't know.. not my dataset